# jquery on dynamic generated content

Tags: jquery, dynamic, live

I have a little problem with JQuery dynamic generated content.

I have this page:

http://velapazza.it/store/index.php/camicia-cotone-manica-lunga/camicia-cotone-modello-101.html

I use JQueryZoom (from Jack Moore), and it works fine. The problem is when I click on the thumbnails......with JQuery I replace the main photo with the clicked one (with the **html()** method), and the zoom doesnt work.

I am using JQuery 1.9.1 version, which and as you know doesnt support the **live()** method; instead of that I used the on() method, but nothing seems to work....

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance

M:)

Comment: Call the plugin again after you replaced the elements.

Comment: Are you adding the images by ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you binding the zoom onto the img once its replaced? I would recommend that when you click on the thumbnail you remove the zoom element from the original and then bind it once the image has been replaced:

```
$('#example').trigger('zoom.destroy'); // remove zoom
$('#example').zoom(); // add zoom
```

Comment: Yeees!!!......I made this and now it works!!....THANKS!!

I post the code, maybe can help someone:

jQuery('.product-image-zoom').zoom();   
    
    jQuery('a.thumb').on('click',function(){
        var img = jQuery(this).children('img');
        var id = img.attr('id');
        var img_path = img.prop('src');
        
        jQuery('.product-image-zoom').html('<img id="'+id+'" src="'+img_path+'" width="480" height="480">');         
        
        jQuery('.product-image-zoom').trigger('zoom.destroy'); // remove zoom
        jQuery('.product-image-zoom').zoom(); // add zoom

    });

Answer (score 1):

If you are performing the zoom as per given example. i.e on document ready state. change it to on hover of your image or div like below

```
$(".your-div or img").hover(function(){
  $('a.photo').zoom({url: 'photo-big.jpg'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If adding elements dynamically i would suggest to using on() at the document:

```
$(document).on("click", ".container .image" . function(){
    ....
});
```

This will active the action for the elements matching the selector event if they were added later.

To apply the plugin on load you should add the instance routine to your ajax load:

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",   
     url: "your provider",   
     async: true,
     success : function(text)
     {
         ....
         jQuery(text).appendTo(container); 

         newElement.pluginName();
     }
});
```

Comment: That will allow to handle events on the new elements, but it doesn't apply the plugin to new elements.